# Django serializer data

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I need to get value of basket in 'title' not in 'id'.

How can I do this? How can I get a value of 'title' from 'Position' model in another 'Client' model using ManyToManyField. It automatically transmits ID and the 'title' is required

I have tried many ways but... It must be easy, but i search info  2 days

```
class Position(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Title')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Describe')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/", verbose_name='Photo', null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, verbose_name='Price')
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date create')
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Date update')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Is published')
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='In stock')


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    basket = models.ManyToManyField('Position', default=None, blank=True, related_name='basket')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}, id-{self.user.id}'
```

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = "__all__"
```

```
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
       # need a list of objects, not an one
        return Client.objects.filter(pk=pk)
```

result:

```
{
"id": 1,
"user": 1,
"basket": [
1
]
}
```

need something like this -  "basket":['monitor','keyboard']

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# need to get title from Position, not id
basket = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_position')
class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = "__all__"

def get_position(self, obj):
    list = Client.objects.get(id=obj.id).basket.all()
    return [position.title for position in list]
```

Dont throw at me the tomatoes, i only at the beginning of the way of programming:)

the need to use get_position method arises bacause the data in Client-table
is stored in Id